# Автоматическое преобразование разрешения набора данных в нейронной сети Yolo*

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

**Имеется:**

Несколько сотен картинок различных разрешений с изображением автомобиля на них и текстовый файл с labels для машины на этих самых картинках.

**Проблема:**

В интернете написано, что Yolo модели сами преобразуют все картинки для обучения в одно разрешение с сохранением aspect ratio, поэтому ничего преобразовывать не нужно, то тогда возникает вопрос:

1. Что происходит при обучении **Yolo**-модели с использованием лейбелов для машин которые я делал, используя картинки разного разрешения. А теперь, когда моделька сама преобразует все разрешения картинок в одно, то преобразует ли она и labels для этих картинок?

**Комментарий:**

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Вот пример лейбела для одной картинки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На последнем фото я представил пример: две фотографии, первая до авто-преобразования и вторая после (это как представляю себе я), а лейбел для этой машины одинаков остается или нет? Если одинаков, то во втором случае он будет неверен.

Answer (score 1):

Из комментария пользователя @Nerxis -

> In that case it's also done automatically, Darknet will resize both
> your image including box labels so you do not have to worry about.

стало понятно, что Yolo модели делают **преобразование** ваших лейбелов ТОЖЕ **автоматически.**